# Template Argument 2 is invalid

Tags: c++

I keep getting the following errors :

```
utils.h:22:39: error: template argument 4 is invalid
utils.h:21:24: error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

When I try to compile :

```
class Words { 
    map <string, *Words > synonyms;  
    map <string, map<string, *Words> > translations; 
};
```

I don't quite understand what makes it an invalid argument. The error arrow is pointing to the ">" symbols. The purpose of the class is to build a dictionary using AVL TreeMaps.

Comment: It should probably be `Words*`.

Comment: This doesn't look like a reasonable class to represent either an individual word or an entire dictionary.

Comment: I don't think you *are* getting those errors - your [mcve] doesn't have line 22 or line 21.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `map<string, Words*>`.

But you might want to reconsider using bare pointers at all.

```
class Words
{
    std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Words>> synonyms;
    std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Words>>> translations;
};
```